# Spring Boot Application Properties in Helm Charts

Tags: java, spring, azure, kubernetes

I have a Spring boot application, that now I generated a helm chart for it. I am using the ConfigMap from k8s to create this application properties. But When I inspect the pod I see the error below:

> 2021-05-31 09:39:31.815  WARN 1 --- [ost-startStop-1]
> o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc
> url from datasource
>
> org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not
> get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is
> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to
> obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

I wrote the application properties as a ConfigMap:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myconfigmap
data:
  application.properties: |-
    server.port = 8080
    spring.datasource.url={{ .Values.database.url }}
    spring.datasource.username={{ .Values.database.username }}
    spring.datasource.password={{ .Values.database.password }}
```

In deployment.yaml I call this using it:

```
      envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: myconfigmap
```

I overwrite the .Values.database... using the keyvault from azure. How is the best way to make this file available on my k8s cluster?

I have the variables overwritten with this command:

> helm upgrade --namespace namescpace --install --set
> "database.url=database_url,database.username=username,database.password=password"
> name_application chartname

main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
```

public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

```
/**
 * Main method.
 *
 * @param args
 *            args passed to the Spring Boot App. Can be used to set the
 *            active profile.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

/**
 * Configure method for enabling deployment in external tomcat.
 *
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you share your spring boot main class ?

Comment: I have updated with the main method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't inject files as env-var. Only simple key=value entries.

If you want to keep your configMap as-is you should instead mount it as a volume inside your container.

```
          volumeMounts:
          - name: application-config 
            mountPath: "/config" 
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: application-config
        configMap:
          name: myconfigmap
          items:
          - key: application.properties 
            path: application.properties
```

Application.properties will now be dropped under /config directory.

Spring will load the mounted file at startup following the documentation : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files